Yup Dynamic field names and types
using Yup for schema creation, is there a way to handle dynamic field names and type (string, number etc).
The fields are coming from an external API and there's a dropdown that can change the subsequent fields.
I tried checking the documentation but there weren't much samples to glean on.
I had experience with multi forms and passing the values up to the parent but this kind of problem is a first for me.
field data looks like: { fieldName: 'someName', fieldType: 'typeHere' }
